# App review feature not working in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, ios11

I've a feature in my iOS application for rating/review application as it redirect user to the app store to to rate my app. now this feature was perfectly run upto iOS 10.3 version. As recently iOS 11 update this feature not working in my app as it shown **cannot connect to app store** whenever I redirect to app store from my app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your need to add add **&action=write-review** to the end of the url.

For en example :

```
let url = URL(string: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/YOUR_APP_ID?mt=8&action=write-review)!
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],completionHandler: { (isOpened) in
})
```

Not tested yet but might be worked.

Comment: my application updated version has not been updated yet on app store as ios 11 already updated. So, it may be not able to found my app url on app store for review. let me update the build and confirm. thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to iOS 11 and it works well, are you using this method?

```
let url = url of your app in app store
UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:],completionHandler: { (isOpened) in

})
```

Comment: my application updated version has not been updated yet on app store as ios 11 already updated. So, it may be not able to found my app url on app store for review. let me update the build and confirm. thank you for your reply